# Mac: Extend or disable 500 Messages Limit of Console

Tags: macos, console.app

On Mac OS X's Console.app I get the following message while trying to find a problem in a software-component:

```
28.07.10 12:09:25   [0x0-0x1ed1ed].org.eclipse.eclipse[6803]    *** process 6803 exceeded 500 log message per second limit  -  remaining messages this second discarded ***
```

(It's a software based on the eclipse osgi framework).

Is there a way to get rid of this 500 Messages Limit? I want to see ALL messages being generated (I have no way to limit the message-amount because it's a 3rd party program).

thanks and greetings,
michael

Answer (score 4):

Got it!

1. Edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` by adding:

   `<string>-mps_limit</string>`
   `<string>0</string>`

   To the program arguments section (below the following line): `<string>/usr/sbin/syslogd</string>`
2. Restart the syslog daemon with:
   `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist; sleep 1; launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist`

A value of 0 disables the limit. The default is 500 messages per second.

PS: If you can't edit the file directly, copy it to a temporary directory, edit that, and then sudo copy it to the original location.

Comment: I have tried this technique. I am not allowed to save the document? I also tried to change user rights. Does not work!

Answer (score 1):

As an update to Michael Mangeng's answer, on macOS El Capitan and later the `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` file is binary so the steps become:

1. Edit `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` using `defaults`:

   `defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist ProgramArguments -array-add -mps_limit 0`

   If `defaults` gives an `Unexpected argument -mps_limit` error, you can rewrite the full ProgramArguments array with the following:

   `defaults write /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist ProgramArguments -array /usr/sbin/syslogd -mps_limit 0`
2. Use `defaults read /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` to confirm the ProgramArguments key appears correct
3. Restart the syslog daemon:

   `launchctl unload /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist; launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist`