# Mac Console.app not logging any messages

Tags: mac, logging, console, console.app

I recently attempted to overcome the 500 message limitation on console logs using the advice provided here:

[Mac: Extend or disable 500 Messages Limit of Console](https://superuser.com/questions/168727/mac-extend-or-disable-500-messages-limit-of-console)

I copied the PLIST file onto my desktop, made the modifications, and re-copied into the LaunchDaemon folder.  No dice.  Unfortunately, this also broke logging in general- the console hasn't logged a message since I attempted this switch.  I even went back and undid my changes.  Still no logs.  What's going on?  Is there a way to reinstall Console.app, or revert to original settings?

Edit- Looks like it's not Console.app's fault.  I just checked the the system.log, nothing has been written to it since before I modified the plist.

Comment: Did you restart the syslog daemon?

Comment: Yes, using the Terminal commands listed with the post.  I restarted after attempting the change, then again (multiple times) since reverting back to the original plist.

Comment: You said you restored the original plist, but does `plutil /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` give any syntax errors? Have you tried adding sudo or -w to `launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist`? Is syslogd running in the background?

Comment: @Lri, that did the trick!  Well, that and a restart.  Would you mind posting your comment as an answer so that I may resolve the question?

Comment: Adding sudo or -w? You can just post it as an answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up permissions issues, then restarting syslogd.plist using `sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.syslogd.plist` successfully brought the log back online.

As an aside, I tried this same technique with the plist modifications noted in the case linked in my original post, and have now successfully lifted the 500 message limit.